# Browser-Router from react-router-dom is giving me an error about hooks and i dont know what the cause is

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

i'm working on a project in react js and i want to create the routes to navigate to different pages, but when i use Browser router from react-router-dom it gives me the error:

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

here is the code:

`

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Welcome from './Components/Pages/Welcome/Welcome';
import QAMAR from './Components/Pages/Landing/Landing';
import ErrorBoundary from './Components/Error'

function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<QAMAR />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

this is my index.js file:

`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

`

and this is the QAMAR component:

`

```
import React from 'react';
import './Landing.css'
import Header from '../../Header/Header';
import Nav from '../../Nav/Nav';
import hero1 from '../../../Assets/MqQ02C.png';
import hero2 from '../../../Assets/wp5918682.png';


export default class QAMAR extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }





    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <main>
                    <div className='Hero-Slider'>
                        <Hero />
                    </div>

                    <div className="center-container">
                        <button className="CourseBtn">Courses</button>
                    </div>

                </main>
                <div className='NotesTab/'>
                    <Nav />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const Hero = () => {
    const images = [hero1, hero2]; // Add more images if needed
    const randomImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    return (
        <div className="hero" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${randomImage})` }}>
            <div className='Fade'>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

`

i dont really know why this is happening in an other project this exact code worked